# Apache2 dynamic documentroot depending on URL

Tags: subdomain, apache-2.2, dynamic

I have looked at setting up an Apache server.

I want to run our site `example.com` on the server, as well as testing `test.example.com`.

This I can setup by having two almost identical VirtualHost in the configure file in `sites-available`.

What I then want is a development subdomain, but these need to be unique per developer, e.g. `mol.test.example.com`. Is there a smart way to set this up?

I have setup the production to take data from `/var/www/live/`, the test to take data from `/var/www/test/` and would like the development to take data from e.g. `/var/www/dev/mol/`, where `mol` is the first part of the URL. (the sub-subdomain for `test`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`VirtualDocumentRoot` should do the trick.

Something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testsites.domain.com
    ServerAlias *.test.domain.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/dev/%1
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to avoid the `testsites.domain.com`? Where does this even send people?

Comment: It's placeholder garbage - you can put `ServerName i.like.cheese` in there for the same effect.

Comment: But setting it to `testsites.domain.com` gives me an error when going to `testsites.domain.com`. Setting it to `i.like.cheese` seems a bit better :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/%1
</VirtualHost>

RewriteRule ^/photo/(.*) /open.php?id=$1 [L,NE,PT]
```

http://rustyrazorblade.com/2009/01/using-mod_rewrite-with-virtualdocumentroot/