# Wildcard substituion in apache virtualhost file

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm trying to set up a single apache virtualhost file that will route xyz.mycompany.com to /var/www/html/development/xyz/public

Here is my hard-coded version.  Is there a way to swap "xyz" with a variable?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xyz.mycompany.com
    ServerAlias xyz.mycompany.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/development/xyz/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html/development/xyz>
        AllowOverride All
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this one as well: [Apache2 dynamic documentroot depending on URL](https://serverfault.com/questions/291891/apache2-dynamic-documentroot-depending-on-url)

You can do this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xyz.mycompany.com
    ServerAlias *.mycompany.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/development/%1/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html/development>
        AllowOverride All
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Regarding the `<Directory>` part, I think you can set your options for the entire development directory.

Comment: Update: "DocumentRoot" needs to be "VirtualDocumentRoot", and you have to run `a2enmod vhost_alias` to install the VirtualDocumentRoot command beforehand.  Finally, run `service apache2 reload`

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

[`mod_macro`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_macro.html) can do variable substitution in config files. However your subject says "wildcard substitution" and certainly Apache config files can handle `*`. In your case `ServerAlias *.mycompany.com` would send any host headers for any subdomain off of mycompany.com into your `/var/www/html/development/xyz` directory.

Comment: Thanks Wesley.  I think lulian's answer more closely matches what I'm looking for. I'm trying to match the subdomain to the directory.